# Windows 8 WEP with Shared Key

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, wep

Windows 8 won't let you connect to a wireless network that uses WEP with shared-key authentication.

That's awesome for the greater good and all, but right now I want the "do it anyway" button, and if you run Windows 8's network diagnostics wizard, it hints that one exists:

> The wireless network that you are trying to connect to requires shared-key authentication, a low security setting that is not recommended by Windows. ...
>
> If you want to connect to this network without changing security settings, you need to manually create a profile.

I created a profile using the "Manually connect to a wireless network" wizard, but there does not seem to be any option to choose shared-key.

How do I create a profile for shared-key authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Found this on a Microsoft(site) forum, from a 'frozenjim':

Open the network and Sharing Center.
Select "Set up a new connection or Network"
Select "Manually connect to a wireless network"
Enter Network name-  this is case sensitive.
Save.

Now the problem you are likely having:

Ether choose the change settings or find the network profile you just created under Manage Wireless Networks, and open it up.

On the "Security tab" you will see Security Type is  "No authentication (Open)".  You likely have to set it to "Shared".  Now you have to re-enter your security key.

My own alternative answer: bite the bullet and actually install the vendor-specific software for your WiFi chipset, be it Realtek or Intel or Broadcom or otherwise.  It probably wouldn't care as much.

Comment: "You likely have to set it to 'Shared'." Windows 8 has no such option. Installing the vendor-specific software seems the only way.